# What are the keyboard shortcuts for navigating a YouTube search result list?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

When I search YouTube, is there a shortcut for choosing the first/second/third... etc. video I'm offered?

When I search `YouTube keyboard shortcuts`, I only see YouTube **player** keyboard shortcuts such as play and pause.